# Application Spyder launch may have produced errors Mac M1 Chip

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder, apple-m1

Hey dear I am trying to launch spyder on my anaconda environment but I face this errors.

*Application Spyder launch may have produced errors **Mac M1 Chip***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/bin/spyder", line 7, in 
from spyder.app.start import main
File "/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 35, in 
from spyder.utils.external import lockfile
File "/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/utils/external/lockfile.py", line 31, in 
from spyder.utils.programs import is_spyder_process
File "/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/utils/programs.py", line 30, in 
import psutil
File "/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 159, in 
from . import _psosx as _psplatform
File "/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 15, in 
from . import _psutil_osx as cext
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found. Did find:
/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/nawrozmohammadi/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

**Befor I launch spyder I installed Tensorflow  through these two ways
[first](https://www.ai-buzz.com/18-steps-to-install-tensorflow_macos-on-m1-macbook-2020/) and [second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i_LLwMS-Xo) and Tensorflow working successfully **

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
>>>tf.__version__
'2.4.0-rc0'
```

I have tried installing pyqt and did

> conda update --all

.But nothing works

**System info**

conda version : 4.9.2

python version: 3.8.6

platform : maOS BigSur 64

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda runs on x86 (intel) hence even i have faced many issues with the m1 macbook air. But miniconda is specifically tailored for arm64 chips.

hence try to install miniconda and use jupyternotebooks.

Follow the below guide to install tensorflow and Pycharm successfully:

[Installation of TensorFlow & Pytorch on M1 Macbooks](https://naturale0.github.io/machine%20learning/setting-up-m1-mac-for-both-tensorflow-and-pytorch#:%7E:text=Macs%20with%20ARM64%2Dbased%20M1,both%20from%20consumers%20and%20developers.)